# Component method response object data binding

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am starting to lose my mind in debugging an application that I inherited from a fellow developer who is absent.
I have narrowed down the problem to the following place in code (php files are checked, Vue instances are initialised, there are no syntax errors).

This is my the component that gets initialised:

```js
var RadniStol = Vue.component('radnistol', {
template: '#template-RadniStol',
data() {
  return {
    tableData: [],
    requestData: {
      sort: "ID",
      order: "DESC"
    }
  }
},
 methods: {
  reloadTable: function (event) {
      data = this.requestData;
      this.$http.post('php/get/radni_stol.php', data).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.bodyText);
          this.tableData = response.data.records;
      });
  },
.
.
.
```

The PHP file that gets called with the POST method is working correctly, querying the database and echoing the response in a JSON format.

The thing that is making me pull out my hair is the following: the console.log(response.data) outputs the following into the console:

```js
{"records":[{"DODAN_NA_RADNI_STOL":"1","..."}]}
```

It is an JSON object that I expected to have but when trying to assign it to the data of the component with:

```js
this.tableData = response.data;
```

or any other way… response.data.records returns ‘undefined’ in the console. I have tryed with JSON.parse() but no success.

When logging types to console:
response variable is a response object with a status 200 and body and bodyText containing the data from the database.
response.data is a string type containing the string JSON with the data from the database.

When trying to use JSON.parse(response.data) or JSON.parse() on anything in the callback of the POST method I get the following error in the console:

`RadniStol.js?version=0.1.1:17 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at VueComponent.$http.post.then.response (RadniStol.js?version=0.1.1:17)
    at <anonymous>`

I am really starting to lose my mind over this issue, please help!

Thank you

Comment: what is it printing to console when you do `response.data.bodyText` ? Or else try to put breakpoint when you print `response.data.records` and check what you are getting from backend and debug it.

Comment: trying to access anything from response.data returns 'undefined'
The php file returns the data that I expect but the problem is in accessing the data

Comment: can u show data coming from server side? for example `response`. you can use pastebin to paste all the data.

Comment: I can't show the data since it is sensitive and not my ownership but when I inspect it it is a valid Response object with a JSON object in the data field.
The backend part is fine, I checked the PHP script and the database query and it is all fine.
It seems to me that the problem is on the Vue or javascript side

Comment: If you think everything is fine from your side, then response.data should give you the JSON sent by backend. I understand that, data is sensitive. you can modify and show the dummy data. Otherwise I can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

If `response.data` is string, with JSON inside, then to access the `records` field, you should decode it like this:

```
JSON.parse(response.data).records
```

Not sure this has something to do with PHP or Vue.js, it is just plain javascript issue.

If it not decodes, than problem is definitely in `response.data`. For example

```
{"records":[{"DODAN_NA_RADNI_STOL":"1","..."}]}
```

is not a valid JSON, because key `"..."` needs to have some value.

But it seems to me that `response.data` is already parsed.

What I suggest you to do, is to write handler of the response as separate function, make response object that mimics actual response object by hand, and then test it separately from request. So you could show us request object and function that works with it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i tried that, edited my question with that error included, thanks

Comment: Also the "..." is just something i put in so i don't paste the whole JSON, same with my code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and fixed it.
Result will be `response.body` not `response.data`.
Here is my code:

```
getS: function(page) {
    this.$http.get('vue-manager?page=' + page).then((response) => {
        var data = JSON.parse(response.body); 
        this.student = data.data.data;
        this.pagination = data.pagination;
    });
},
```